Is there alternative way to update query params without rerendering the page?
Shallow routing and window replaceState is not working.Is there alternative way to update query params without rerendering the page?
router.replace({ pathname: router.pathname, query: rest, }, undefined, { shallow: true }) shallow true is re rendering the page

The router object is changing, which means any page calling useRouter necessarily will re-render. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you not want it to re-render?

Scenario: When I first navigate to a page, I want to perform a certain action by looking at a url parameter, say id. Once the id exists, I want to scroll in to a specific element in the page. Once the scroll is completed, I want to remove the id from the url without reloading the page.
